2024-12 CompilerOptions does not have member field 'long originalComplianceLevel'
After installing the update to 2024-12 I get the following error within Eclipse Scout SDK:
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.impl.CompilerOptions does not have member field 'long originalComplianceLevel'
    at org.eclipse.scout.sdk.core.java.ecj.EcjAstCompiler.createDefaultOptions(EcjAstCompiler.java:60)

any ideas?
seems to be an incompatibility with org.eclipse.jdt.ecj but I do not see which version my IDE or Scout is using.
FormData classes are not updated automatically.
Update all Derived Resources... leads as well to ther error

This is a bug in the 2024-12 release of the Eclipse Scout SDK plugin.
You can try to update your Eclipse 2024-12 to the nightly version which includes a fix:

Go to Help -> Install new Software...
Enter "https://download.eclipse.org/scout/nightly/13.0/" in the "Work with" URL field and hit enter to populate the list.
In the list below category "Scout Application Development SDK" select "Eclipse Scout SDK" (choose at least version 13.0.0.20241209-2344)
Press Next and wait until all alternate solutions have been computed.
Choose alternate solution "Update my installation to be compatible with the items being installed" and press Next. This uninstalls the existing and installs the nightly version.
On the "Install Details" page review the config and press Finish.
Restart the IDE after the changes have completed.


Thank you Matthias, worked fine. One thing you should check. You deployed the nightly fix with version 13.0.0 - shouldn't it be 13.0.47 or similar. With the actual one, Eclipse would like to reinstall 13.0.46 if you check for new software.

Nightly builds always use the 13.0.0 version. 13.0.46 or similar are release builds.
A fresh release build including the fix will come as part of the next Scout build cycle (which is independent of the Eclipse release cycle).
Then the fix will be picked up by the normal "check for updates" within Eclipse (even without installing a nightly version)
